# How to convert JSON to tsv using jq in unix?

Tags: json, csv, unix, jq

I need to convert this JSON to a TSV format. I've a source file like this:

```
{
  "event": "log",
  "timestamp": 1535306331840,
  "tags": [
    "info"
  ],
  "data": {
    "_id": "A301180827005852329209020",
    "msisdn": "6282134920902",
    "method": "get",
    "url": "/api/tcash/balance",
    "timeTaken": 32,
    "channelid": "UX"
  },
  "pid": 7920
}
```

Then I want to convert it to tsv which are consist of below column:

```
event, timestamp, tags, _id, msisdn, method, url, timeTaken, channelID, pid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to construct an array of atomic values.  Since `.tags` is not atomic, in the following I'll assume (as suggested by @chepner) that we can use `.tags|join(",")`, though you might want to use something else, such as `.tags|@csv`:

```
[.event, .timestamp, (.tags | join(","))]
+ (.data|[._id, .msisdn, .method, .url, .timeTaken, .channelID])
+ [.pid]
| @tsv
```

Comment: I would assume that `"info"` is one of possibly several tags, in which case the `tags` column should be some sort of delimited list, e.g. `["info", "stuff", "things"]` would become `info,stuff,things`.

Comment: @chepner - Yes, I misread the JSON, and have updated the answer. Tx.